# Mcrypt issue with PHP, Nginix, Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, encryption, mcrypt

I am working on an app where we are sharing login/session across the sub domains. To do this, we are generating some encrypted information but we are facing issue with `mcrypt`. Our code stuck on a point and never comes back unless the time out occurs. 
To encrypt data we use following function

```
 $cipher = new Cipher(env('CYPHER_KEY'));

return $cipher->encrypt($str);
```

And on encrypt function of Cipher class, the very first line is creating problem that is:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size);
```

This is a php function of mcrypt library. `$this->iv_size` contains 16. When execution comes to this line, it never comes back and it doesn't throw any error, exception in any log. It just stuck here unless ngnix throws time out error.

I am using `Laravel 5.2 (Php5, php-fpm), ngnix and Ubuntu 14.04`. I have already installed and enable mcrypt extension and I can see it when I do `php -m`.

Can any body please guide me what I am doing wrong here or how can I even get some error string to debug/fix.

Comment: As an aside - mcrypt is deprecated and will be removed in PHP 7.2; might be worth looking at [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) instead.

Comment: What version of PHP? There's apparantly a bug with PHP v < 5.6.18 in that `mcrypt_create_iv` will hang; see: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/90 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69833

Comment: @WillParky93 I have this issue on dev server where php version is `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (cli)` but it is working fine on production where php version is `PHP 5.6.13-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 (cli)`

Comment: Then I think your solution is to update your dev server. Curious why your dev server isn't running the same version of PHP as prod. Seems like a disaster waiting to happen. The bug I stated looks like it existed in 5.5.9 and was actually fixed in `5.6.11`, not `5.6.18` as I originally wrote

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.